# NodeJS doesn't resolve path properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, resolve

I have a nodeJS server with many modules and nested modules I want to startup while console.logging a message so I made something like this.

```
global.REQUIRE = function(path) {
    console.log('loading module ' + path);
    return require(path);
};
```

And instead of having `require('./constants/app-constants.js')` I would have `global.REQUIRE('./constants/app-constants.js');`. 
But path isn't properly resolved because I have some nested modules and REQUIRE method is in application-main.js on root folder so require solves from there apparently. I don't think it's wrong I just comment my first attemp.

My second attempt was then using require('path').resolve and do something like this.

```
var resolve = require('path').resolve;
global.REQUIRE(resolve('./constants/app-constants.js'));
```

But this doesn't properly resolve either. Console outputs something like

> /home/$USER/git/nodeJS/constants/app-constants.js

instead of what should output

> /home/$USER/git/nodeJS/**app**/constants/app-constants.js

**index.js** with the requires is inside app/ folder and old `require('./constants/app-constants.js')` works fine from there.

Comment: Would something like `require.resolve()` https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve give you what you want?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you.